# Column 'group_ID' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php

I have this error message:

> Column 'group_ID' in field list is ambiguous:

Below is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members(email, name, gender, dob, profile, password, group_ID) 
        SELECT group_ID 
        FROM operations
        JOIN members
        WHERE operations.group_ID = members.group_ID" ;

$result = $db->query($query);
```

Trying to insert data into members table, group_ID is from operations but it is a column in the members table.

Comment: in the "select group_ID ...." you will have to specify which group_ID you are talking about, whether it is operations.groupID or members.group_ID

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask at some point

Answer (score 0):

Your insert won't work, you should learn insert query and join query first, for reference :[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) and then do something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members(email, name, gender, dob, profile, password, group_ID)
          VALUES(email_value,name_value,gender_value,dob_value,profile_value,password_value,( 
          SELECT members.group_ID 
          FROM operations
          JOIN members
          ON operations.group_ID = members.group_ID) where condition=some_condition)" ;

$result = $db->query($query);
```